# C++ pass pointers to a Template class function

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

I am new to C++ (more of a java guy). I am trying to teach myself about C++ pointers. Here I've created two classes, `Person` (The base class), and the `Student` (Derived class).

I tried to put `Student` objects in an `unordered_map<string, Person>`. But met an error.

This is my code:

```
class Person
{
  protected:
    string name;
    int age;

  public:
    int getAge()
    {
      return age;
    }
    string getName()
    {
      return name;
    }
};

class Student : public Person
{
  private:
    string grade;

  public:
    Student(string const &name, int const &age, string const &grade)
    {
      this -> name = name;
      this -> age = age;
      this -> grade = grade;
    }
    int getAge();
};
```

Here's my main function:

```
int main()
{
  unordered_map<string, Person *> students;
  Student s("Sam", 26, "A");
  Person *p;
  p = &s;

  students.insert(p -> getName(), p);

  return 0;
}
```

**This is just a part of the code, and I know it looks foolish. But I'm just learning about pointers**

I have included `<iostream>` and `<unordered_map>` libraries and using `namespace std` here.

Error message is so long. Can someone point out the error I made here ? Or, should I post that long error message also ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use students.insert({p -> getName(), p});

Comment: *"Error message is so long."* And the answer is *"too large to fit in the margin"* :-)

Comment: But, what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: @Jarod42 It's rude to post sarcastic comments, while someone is asking for help !

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge: I mean help us to help you. Providing (part of) the error message can help to have answer. `insert` take a `std::pair` parameter, so you have to construct `pair` or use other method as `emplace`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Jarod42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am more of a java guy.

Here's what you need to know:

## Pointers

`Person*` is a pointer to a person - a pointer simply carries the address of an object in memory. It's as low level as you can get. It's equivalent to using an address register or index register in assembly language. It carries no information about object lifetime and does not influence object lifetime in any way. It is 100% abusable. Use with care, if ever.

## Shared references

```
// java code
var x = new Y();
var y = x;

// equivalent c++
auto x = std::make_shared<Y>();
auto y = x;
```

If you want java-like behaviour, then `std::shared_ptr<Person>` is equivalent to a java object reference. It shares ownership of the person and allows (actually in c++ mandates) that the Person is destroyed when all of the shared_ptrs have gone out of scope or have been reset.

## Unique reference with lifetime control

Between the two is a `std::unique_ptr<Person>` which will cause the automatic destruction of the Person when the one and only unique_ptr is destroyed or reset. You cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr` so it can't be used to share references to an object. It can however, be converted to a `shared_ptr` (this implicitly empties the unique_ptr).

## Weak references

Then there is a `std::weak_ptr<Person>` which is the weak counterpart to a `std::shared_ptr<Person>`. It cannot be de-referenced directly but must first be converted to a `shared_ptr` with the `lock()` method. This provides an atomic 'test for existence and lock into place' operation. We use it to resolve or avoid resource leaks caused by circular references (which java claims not to have on account of garbage collection).

## Lifetime differences between Java and C++

In Java, when there are no more reachable references to an object, it becomes a candidates for garbage collection. At some point in the future, it may or may not be recovered.

C++ is different and more predictable. When the `unique_ptr` or the last `shared_ptr` controlling an object's lifetime is reset, that object's destructor will be executed immediately and in the same thread. It's completely sequential. This gives rise to the possibility of RAII, and allows us to use object lifetimes to cause code to execute no matter what the execution path.

This is also arguably why there is no need for `finally` in c++. Resource cleanup goes in the destructors of resource owners.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the more detailed and explained answer. This is a great help !

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, except for one line:

```
students.insert(p -> getName(), p);
```

Here you probably meant that you want to place `p` to the cell `p->getName()`, but, unfortunately, [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) has no instance to take a key and a value as two arguments. Passing them as one argument or using `operator[]` should help:

```
students[p->getName()] = p;
students.insert({p->getName(), p});
students.insert(std::make_pair(p->getName(), p));
```

I personally would select first option as more readable, if possible.

**UP:** As @Jarod42 commented, the first option here requires the value type to be default constructible, which is not always an option.

Comment: The first option requires that value is default constructible, which is not always the case. `emplace` is an other possibility.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, it's an important clarification. Will add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @alexeykuzmin0

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
  unordered_map<string, Person *> students;
  Student s("Sam", 26, "A");
  Person *p;
  p = &s;

  pair<string, Person*> item("key", p);
  students.insert(item);

  return 0;
}
```